# ajax form submission message error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

`project` has one `project_director`, project_director has attribute `status`
earlier i was not using ajax to submit project_director form page was getting reloaded each time and submission `status` was accessed accordingly.

now i using ajax data gets submitted without page reload but i not able to hide from after status value is set once, neither i am able to show any message on submission. how can i show submitted value in row and hide form after submission using ajax feature.

here is my current code:-

index.html.erb

```
<% if project_site.project_directors.empty?%>
  <%= form_for ProjectDirector.new, :remote => true do |f| %>
    <td>
     <table class="approval-table">
      <tr>
       <td>
        <ul>
         <div>
          <div class="wrapper-class">
           <%= f.radio_button :status, true  %>
           <%= f.label :approve %>
           <br>
           <%= f.radio_button :status, false  %>
           <%= f.label :reject %>
          </div>
          <%=f.hidden_field :project_site_id, value: project_site.id%>
         </div>
        </ul>
       </td>
       <td>
        <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
        <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'button primary small' %>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <% project_site.project_directors.each do |project_director| %>
    <% if project_director.status == false %>
      <td class="rejected fi-x"><%= ' Rejected' %></td>
    <% elsif project_director.status == true %>
      <td class="approved fi-check"><%= " Approved" %></td>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

project_directors_controller.rb

```
def create
  @project_director =  ProjectDirector.new(remark_params)
  #redirect_to  directors_index_path, anchor: '#panel2'
  if @project_director.save
    if request.xhr?
      render json: { success: true }
    else
      redirect_to notice: "Thing was successfully created."
    end
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the DOM when the success method is called on your save request. You can do so by creating a `create.js.erb` file that will execute some JS.

1. You can change your controller to use `respond_to`

```
def create
  @project_director = ProjectDirector.new(remark_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @project_director.save
      format.js   { render layout: false }
      format.html { redirect_to notice: "Thing was successfully created." }
    else
      format.js   { render layout: false }
      format.html { render :new }
    end
  end
end
```

2. Split your HTML into partials.

```
<div id="project_site_view">
  <% if project_site.project_directors.empty?%>
     <%= render 'from' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'project_directors', locals: { project_site: project_site } %>
  <% end %>
</div>

# _form.html.erb
<%= form_for ProjectDirector.new, :remote => true do |f| %>
  <td>
   <table class="approval-table">
    <tr>
     <td>
      <ul>
       <div>
        <div class="wrapper-class">
         <%= f.radio_button :status, true  %>
         <%= f.label :approve %>
         <br>
         <%= f.radio_button :status, false  %>
         <%= f.label :reject %>
        </div>
        <%=f.hidden_field :project_site_id, value: project_site.id%>
       </div>
      </ul>
     </td>
     <td>
      <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
      <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'button primary small' %>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
<% end %>

# _project_directors.html.erb
<% project_site.project_directors.each do |project_director| %>
  <% if project_director.status == false %>
    <td class="rejected fi-x"><%= ' Rejected' %></td>
  <% elsif project_director.status == true %>
    <td class="approved fi-check"><%= " Approved" %></td>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

3. Render the partials in your `create.js.erb`

```
<% if @project_director.errors.any? %>
  <!-- handle error here -->
<% else %>
  $("#project_site_view").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'project_directors', locals: { project_site: @project_director.project_site } ) %>"); 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you check the network tab to see if this request is going through correctly? I've not changed anything from your code.

Comment: checked network, nothing happens on form submit now